# Dart - Consistent hash code between executions of the same program

Tags: dart

The `hashCode` of object in the Dart has need not be consistent between executions of the same program
But I have a use case that need to be consistent between executions of the same program

How can I have a consistent hashCode?

Comment: If your class overrides `operator ==` and `hashCode` so that it doesn't rely solely on object identity, your `hashCode` implementation will naturally be deterministic based on your object's properties.

Comment: Assume I have an object and save it's hash to a persistent storage, After closing and opening application If I have the same object, I want to `assert(object.hashCode == persistentHashCode)`, I am looking for an algorithm that help me generate has code

Comment: You're trying to break Dart's `hashCode` abstraction for reasons that don't sound particularly necessary. Why not just write your own new hashing function for the object — `getPersistentHash()` or whatever? Stringify and concatenate all the object's fields, and take the MD5 hash of the result.

Comment: @Noah OK, you are right, What is the best `int` hash code? I need low collisions and fast calculation

Comment: [Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed) is a nice review of the kind of non-cryptographic hash function you're looking for. Some of them support 32- or 64-bit output — i.e., integer-sized.